# background image using css

Tags: html, css

I want to display background image in all my web pages.My body css code is

```
body{
  background-image:url('image/silver.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
 }
```

I include this page in my page as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css">
```

But This couldn't display background image now.If I include body css code in head section It display background image.

Comment: check your path? `"../css/body.css/"`, also close the link  tag `<link />`

Comment: Right click on the web page and click inspect element. If it gives an error under console tell us what it says.

Comment: or check you bg path `background-image:url('../image/silver.jpg');`

Comment: error in path http://www.sample.com/hr/css/image/silver.jpg my actual path is http://www.sample.com/hr/image/silver.jpg

Comment: How to over come this error.Any one can help me

Answer (score 3):

Paths in CSS are relative to the CSS document, and are not relative to your website's root.

I recommend putting images (and all style assets) in the same directory as the stylesheet to keep paths simpler.

Anyway, change the `background-image` property to this:

```
background-image:url('../image/silver.jpg');
```

...if your site's filesystem is this:

```
index.html
css/
    style.css
image/
    silver.jpg
```

In my opinion, your site should resemble this:

```
index.html
style/
    style.css
    silver.jpg
images/
    // put "content" images here (like a photo of yourself)...
    // ... not "style" images (e.g. a background gradient image).
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are specifying the path to the image correctly. Maybe your CSS file is in a different directory than the HTML file?